# Heavy UDP/sunrpc network usage to unknown IP addresses

Tags: networking, security, udp

In the last week or so, my network monitory has indicated that my desktop computer has started periodically sending ~0.7MB/s out over my ethernet connection (eno).

I understand very little about network protocols, but have been trying to figure out what processes are responsible for this heavy network usage.  Some simple approaches have been to shutdown my web browser, kill dropbox, etc. None of these seem to be the culprit.

I have also tried using `nethogs`, but it doesn't show any process using the network at this level of usage.  I then tried using `iptraf-ng`.  I had a hard time making sense of the output, but I did finally see that most of the traffic was going out over `UDP/sunrpc`.  I tried using this information with `lsof -i:sunrpc` or `lsof -i:111`, but didn't get any information.

Filtering the output from `ipgraf-ng` for sunrpc gives the following

```
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 1500 bytes; from machine.domain.edu:sunrpc to 156.226.77.151:5709
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 68 bytes; from 160.20.57.123:32421 to machine.domain.edu:sunrpc
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 1500 bytes; from machine.domain.edu:sunrpc to 160.20.57.123:32421
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 68 bytes; from 156.226.101.174:39960 to machine.domain.edu:sunrpc
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 1500 bytes; from machine.domain.edu:sunrpc to 156.226.101.174:39960
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 68 bytes; from 103.80.24.127:22853 to machine.domain.edu:sunrpc
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 1500 bytes; from machine.domain.edu:sunrpc to 103.80.24.127:22853
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 68 bytes; from 156.226.125.197:56897 to machine.domain.edu:sunrpc
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 1500 bytes; from machine.domain.edu:sunrpc to 156.226.125.197:56897
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 68 bytes; from 103.30.201.131:27703 to machine.domain.edu:sunrpc
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 1500 bytes; from machine.domain.edu:sunrpc to 103.30.201.131:27703
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 68 bytes; from 154.204.194.227:21216 to machine.domain.edu:sunrpc
Wed Feb 21 14:31:32 2024; UDP; eno1; 1500 bytes; from machine.domain.edu:sunrpc to 154.204.194.227:21216
```

Looking up these ipaddresses gives me concern since they are not associated with any entity that I know of.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: If this is within a college or university, then you need to discuss it with their IT bods. If this is a home network, then you really need to set up a firewall as it appears your system is being used for an amplification attack. You could always run `systemctl stop rpcbind` and see if that helps.

Comment: Per Bib's comment, see: [DNS Amplification Attack](https://www.cisa.gov/news-events/alerts/2013/03/29/dns-amplification-attacks)

Comment: Thank you both for that information.  It was very helpful.  Regarding resolving the issue, it is university computer, but our OIT offers zilch linux support so I'll need to fix this myself.  I'm assuming I need to restrict access to that service to the set of computers that use it as an NFS server.  Correct?

Comment: It does not matter whether it is running Linux or any other os, the uni has a duty of care and that means running a correctly configured firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Bib and @eyoung100, my machine is being used to amplify an DNS attack.  I've stopped and disabled the `rpcbind` service using

```
$ sudo systemctl stop rpcbind
$ sudo systemctl stop rpcbind.socket
```

and

```
$ sudo systemctl disable rpcbind
$ sudo systemctl disable rpcbind.socket
```

since it is not needed (AFAIK). My computer's only real server function is `nfs4.2`.